# What would be the product of this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, hydrolysis

[image]

A 3 membered carbon ring with a double bond to oxygen from one carbon and a double bond between the remaining carbon with a methyl group attached to one of the carbon is made to undergo acid catalyzed hydrolysis. What will be the product?

Comment: The compound is 2-methylcyclopropenone. What do you think of the 4 options offered?

Comment: I was thinking compound A could be more stable due to aromatic stability and would not further react with H2O to form B. However the answer is B.

Comment: A is a charged species and that is not going to be stable in the presence of water. There are lit references to acetals and hydrates of cyclopropenones but they're all behind paywalls.

Comment: According to the official answer key, the answer is given as (A). But I still don't understand how a charged specie is more stable than a neutral specie?